# Route Order With Multiple Dynamic Params

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jsx

My problem is that i cant figure out the best way to handle multiple dynamic params in a deep link without having to have it fully rely on the order of the Routes in the JSX

I'll start by outline the flow of my app.

List of Television Series -> *user clicks series* -> List of Episodes in Series -> *user clicks episode* -> Show stats about episode

after this flow, i want my path to be `/series/:series_id/episode/:episode_id`.

Currently i have this working by setting up my router basically like so:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/series" component={SeriesLibrary} />
    <Route
      path="/series/:series_id/episode/:episode_id"
      component={Episode}
    />
    <Route path="/series/:series_id" component={EpisodeLibrary} />
  </Switch>
</Router
```

but that is relying on the multi-dynamic path (the one with the **series_id** *and* **episode_id**) coming before the one that *just* has the **series_id**!

This is because even when the path is `series/4356/episode/4567` it would match the `series/4356` before ever rendering the Episode component.

Is there a better way for me to address the issue of multiple dynamic deep linked params in react router?

I feel like this cannot be best practice, relying **strictly on the order of JSX elements** for your app to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass exact prop to to EpisodeLibrary:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/series" component={SeriesLibrary} />
    <Route exact path="/series/:series_id" component={EpisodeLibrary} />
    <Route
      path="/series/:series_id/episode/:episode_id"
      component={Episode}
    />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: wow i cant believe that lol... i would've thought that adding exact meant it has to literally match `/series/:series_id` and wouldnt match `/series/4786`

thank you!